# Erro de autentificação de cabeçalho HTTP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-headers

Estou tentando configurar uma API Reseller do Zopim, só que estou enfrentando um problema: A autentificação da API Key e API Secret.

Eu tenho o seguinte código Javascript:

```
<link href="http://static.zopim.com/www_new/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://static.zopim.com/www_new/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.zopim.com/www_new/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.zopim.com/www_new/js/crypto-js/hmac-sha1.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.zopim.com/www_new/js/crypto-js/md5.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.zopim.com/www_new/js/crypto-js/enc-base64-min.js"></script>
<script>

$(function() {
    $('#method').change(function() {
        var method = $(this).val();
        if (method == 'GET' || method == 'DELETE')
            $('#json-group').hide();
        else
            $('#json-group').show();
    });

    $('#send-button').click(function() {
        var url = $('#url').val()
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = url;
        var method = $('#method').val();
        if (method == 'GET')
            var data = '';
        else
            var data = $.trim($('#json').val());
        var md5 = data ? CryptoJS.MD5(data).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64) : '';
        var date = (new Date()).toUTCString();

        var parts = [method, md5, date, a.pathname].join('\n');
        var hmac = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(parts, $('#api_secret').val());
        var sig = hmac.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
        var auth = 'Zopim-Reseller-API ' + $('#api_token').val() + ':' + sig;
        var headers = {'API-Date': date, Authorization: auth};
        $.ajax({
            type: method,  dataType: "json", url: url, data: data,  headers: headers,

            success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                var d = $('<div class="row">'
                        + '<h3>Request</h3>'
                        + '<pre>'
                        + method + ' ' + a.pathname + a.search + '\n'
                        + 'Authorization: ' + auth + '\n'
                        + 'API-Date: ' + date + '\n'
                        + '</pre>'
                        + '<h3>Success Response: ' + xhr.status + ' '
                        + xhr.statusText
                        + '</h3>'
                        + '<pre>'
                        + JSON.stringify(data, null, " ") + '</pre>');
                $('#first-row').after(d);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                var d = $('<div class="row">'
                        + '<h3>Request</h3>'
                        + '<pre>'
                        + 'Authorization: ' + auth + '\n'
                        + 'API-Date: ' + date + '\n'
                        + '</pre>'
                        + '<h3 style="color:red">Error Response: '
                        + xhr.status + ' ' + xhr.statusText
                        + '</h3>'
                        + '<pre>'
                        + xhr.responseText + '</pre>');
                $('#first-row').after(d);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

<div class="container">
    <h2>Zopim Reseller API Client</h2>
    <div class="row" id="first-row">
        <div class="span10">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">API Credentials</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" id="api_token" placeholder="API Token" value="" />
                            <input type="text" id="api_secret" placeholder="API Secret" value="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">URL</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" id="url" placeholder="URL" style="width: 320px;" value="https://reseller.zopim.com/api/info" />
                            <select id="method" style="width: 100px;">
                                <option>GET</option>
                                <option>PUT</option>
                                <option>POST</option>
                                <option>DELETE</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="json-group" class="control-group" style="display: none;">
                        <label class="control-label">JSON</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <textarea id="json" style="width:450px; height:190px;"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="button" class="btn" id="send-button" value="Request" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Ao executar eu tenho que informar as 2 API (API Key e API Secret), eu informo as duas e me retorna a seguinte mensagem no Chrome:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://reseller.zopim.com/api/info. Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

Gostaria de saber se alguém pode me ajudar, pois estou quebrando a cabeça e não consegui nada.

Comment: Olhando para a documentação __[aqui](https://sites.google.com/a/zopim.com/reseller/api/agents)__ parece-me que o URL devia ser `https://reseller.zopim.com/api/accounts/#{id}`. Porque está a usar `https://reseller.zopim.com/api/info` ?

Comment: https://reseller.zopim.com/api/info é uma URL que pega as informações da conta. Existe inumeras URL's a que estou usando é a info. A accounts é para criar contas.

Comment: Estranho na página da documentação não referir sequer esse `/info`... Não é isto que pretende (SHOW): https://sites.google.com/a/zopim.com/reseller/api/agents#TOC-Show ?

Comment: Na verdade eu quero criar contas apartir do meu site, usando essa API, ou seja, apartir do meu site as pessoas podem criar contas no site do zopim. Então usarei esse https://sites.google.com/a/zopim.com/reseller/api/agents#TOC-Create ... o /info é só uma URL padrão, mas usarei https://reseller.zopim.com/api/accounts

Comment: Fechei esta pergunta como duplicata da mais recente, pois essa última parece ser sobre o mesmo problema num estágio posterior das suas tentativas.